# How large does an object have to be to cause global extinction?

Tags: science-based

I've been trying to explain the origins of a fantasy world I've been constructing. So far, I have the idea of a Promethean (advanced race of aliens) Penal ship crashing (probably from an internal uprising) into the planet.

I need two things to still remain on the planet:

1. Habitable atmosphere so the damage caused by the crash should only be enough to cause an extinction event on the surface.
2. The ability for some ocean and cave creatures to survive.

Now what would be the size (as in what scope do I have to work with) of the ship to cause an extinction upon impact but not make the world uninhabitable.

Note: Due to the nature of the ship, when the ship begins descending to the surface the crew and prisoners would be directed to stasis pods that would allow some to survive the crash. On top of this, the ships AI would only wake them once the atmosphere is safe again (handwave how they can breath the specific atmosphere for now).

Specifics: ship is 2 kilometers in diameter (weight will be added soon) and speed would be roughly 6-8000 kilometers per hour.

Comment: You might want to include things like what the ship is made of.

Comment: Mass and speed are both important. You need to pick speed if you want to determine effects based upon mass. See [XKCD](https://what-if.xkcd.com/20/) for a good example.

Comment: @Piomicron materials would be alloys I have yet to name, but it's lightweight and durable to fit the egragavagent tastes of the Prometheans

Comment: @Walker I will try and figure out a good speed by tonight as well as a rough estimate for mass

Comment: https://youtu.be/uwPuE9VZbUY?t=1601

Comment: You are asking the size of the ship, then state that the ship is 2 km in diameter. So, you answered yourself

Comment: I just added that dutch after someone asked the size. Should I clarify that somewhere?

Comment: 6-8000 kilometers **per hour** is very slow for an extinction event. In this case the ship has to very dense to crash into planetary mantle and cause eruptions on global scale.

Comment: The idea is its going much slower due to the sheer mass, but I have yet to workout the mass. I might just have to speed the ship up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the ship is speeding toward the planet at a relativistic speed, congratulations, you extinguished life on the planet!

Same thing is the ship's hull is made of a hyperdense material. A small ship made of neutronium, even traveling at a handful of Km/s would punch a bad one into the planet.

Or the ship could be packing a ludicrous amount of radioactive material, and its descent could consist of a gliding phase during which it spills said material all over...

**But a problem remains!** A devastating impact requires that the ship is destroyed. In other words, nothing will be left of that artifact. Even the [Chicxulub asteroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicxulub_impactor) was **vaporized** in the impact, and we're talking about a 10-to-15 Km large **mountain** hitting our planet. To make for the same mass, the ship should be several times that asteroid's size, and it would turn into droplets scattering all around the planet for future generations of mineralogists to investigate.

If you want your crew to survive, ship must eject pods, programming them to land on the opposite side of the planet. And since pods are not equipped to keep their content alive for an undefinitely amount of time, they will open automatically and let's cross fingers!

Comment: Eject pods it is!

Comment: What if you tried to drastically slow the ship though?

Comment: Easy: The ship crashlands and will cause significant damage, say, to a city the size of Manhattan, but no global extinction. The crew and the AI are safe, but they are sequestered by the authorities. The ship becomes object of study from all the world's scientists

Comment: or the ship could have a [Larry Niven style Stasis Field](http://larryniven.wikia.com/wiki/Stasis_field)

Comment: Even better! Ships lands safely in the middle of a city, causes damages but nothing compared to a crashland, the crew is safe -in fact, they don't even need to be put in stasis at all. At this point, the whole question is moot like a 3-dollar bill.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you are looking for a way that your ship's arrival can depopulate the planet while leaving it almost instantly available for recolonization.  If that is the case, high velocity impact is not your best bet.  It raises too much dirt and previous inhabitant bits into the air and leads to long term weather issues like ice ages.

Depopulating a planet and totally whipping out its entire ecosystem are two different things.  Using impact, you accomplish both and ruin the planet for everyone.  A better solution involves just a few micro-grams of genetics.

Harmless to its existing crew, your ship might be carrying a disease which is fatal to the planet's current population.  Upon arriving, either by crash or soft landing, you crew just has to exhale a few times, and the planet will soon become vacant yet still inhabitable.  No raging firestorms and resulting ice ages.  Just a little applied genetics and your indigenous population problem is solved.

So your ship can be any size you want.  It is what's inside that counts.

Comment: This could totally work. Luckily the Prometheans mess around with bio-engineering so they could've accidentally created a pathogen.

Comment: There is an old Star Trek Next Generation episode where a deadly disease was actually a pro-active immune system which was the result of genetic engineering.  The immune systems of the enhanced humans actually sought out and destroyed other lifeforms outside of their host's bodies.